# How to get zip file from url using CURL request?

Tags: php, curl, directory, zip, php-curl

I want to get zip file from using PHP CURL request but when i hit that URL in browser it print like that.
[image]

I am using https://gist.github.com/thagxt/d9b4388156aeb7f1d66b108d728470d2 this as a reference.

Like the same i have created extracted folder var/www/html/extracted and my file apth is /var/www/html/data.php but it doesn't create zip file.
I have applied the proper permisssion on that folder as well but didn't any success.

I want to get zip file in that particular folder.

My code is

```
<?php 
$url = "https://wordpress.org/latest.zip"; // URL of what you wan to download
$zipFile = "wordpress.zip"; // Rename .zip file
$extractDir = "extracted"; // Name of the directory where files are extracted
$zipResource = fopen($zipFile, "w");

// Get The Zip File From Server
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $zipResource);

$page = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$page) {
    echo "Error :- ".curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

/* Open the Zip file */
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$extractPath = $extractDir;

if($zip->open($zipFile) != "true"){
    echo "Error :- Unable to open the Zip File";
} 

/* Extract Zip File */
$zip->extractTo($extractPath);
$zip->close();

die('Your file was downloaded and extracted, go check.');
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show us your actual code, instead of just referring to what you “used as reference”. [mre] - always! Also, explain what you actually mean by you want to “get” the zip file. The code you are referring to is supposed to automatically extract the zip file on the server, but from your screenshot, it looks like you get the content of it shown, so you must have output that deliberately, I suppose?

Comment: That code works fine for me on my local machine (after I increase the timeout of 10 seconds a bit, that does not seem to be enough.) I get “Your file was downloaded and extracted, go check.”, it created the `extracted` folder and the WordPress files are in there.

Comment: will you please share your code and the extracted folder is created automatically ot you manually create it .

Comment: I have increased the timeout CURLOPT_TIMEOUT this to 500 but still it shows the data and nothing created on my directory will you please help @CBroe

Comment: I copy&pasted your code as-is, gave me a timeout error first, so I increased it from 10 to 100. I did not create any folders manually upfront, but then again I tested on Windows, so file permissions aren’t that much of an issue in that scenario. Do you have proper error reporting enabled, and did you check the log? If it was any kind of permissions issue, then there should probably be according entries in there. (Although permission issues would still not explain why you get the binary zip content shown in your browser.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220789/discussion-between-prits-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

try to put the response in the file_put_content function like this

file_put_contents('zipname.zip', $response);